# Formato de fecha VB.net EF

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, date, ado.net

```
     Function TraeConta(ByVal DAT_CODIGO As Integer,
                       ByVal DAT_NRO_ORDEN As Integer,
                       ByVal DAT_RUTPAC As Integer) As MIN_CONT_CONTACTADOS


        Dim cont As New MIN_CONT_CONTACTADOS


        Try
            cont = _db.Min_Trae_Contactados(DAT_CODIGO, DAT_NRO_ORDEN, DAT_RUTPAC).First()

            Return cont

        Catch ex As Exception
            ViewBag.Error = ex.Message
            Return cont
        End Try

    End Function
```

dentro de MIN_CONT_CONTACTADOS hay un campo CONT_FECHACONTAC
¿Como le aplico el Formato de retorno yyyy-MM-dd ?

Comment: El formato de fecha es únicamente para cuando vayas a mostrarlo al usuario. Internamente, un campo de fecha no tiene formato.

Comment: Es para mostrarlo al usuario, actualmente el formato que muestra es  dd-mm-yyyy, pero la vista de usuario no me muestra la fecha porque me pide el dato en yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: En ese caso, enseñanos el código donde muestras la fecha al usuario. Simplemente usando  `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");` debería bastar

Comment: Espera,vista? Estas usando mvc?

Comment: si, estoy trabajando con MVC, olvidé mencionarlo

Comment: En ese caso,depende de donde lo estés mostrando, pero sería algo asi como `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CONT_FECHACONTAC, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")`